# OAuth2 with Twitter API 1.1 "Bad Authentication error"

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use the Twitter's API (v1.1) through node.js and Oauth2 but I am getting always the same error:

```
Error: 
{ statusCode: 400,
  data: '{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}' }
```

Here is the snippet of code I am using:

http://pastie.org/8708152

Which is based on:

http://webapplog.com/node-js-oauth1-0-and-oauth2-0-twitter-api-v1-1-examples/

Any help would be appreciated I spent many hours trying to make it work already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the reason it didn't work is that right now Twitter only supports OAuth version 2 for application-based authentication (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth).

For user based authentication you still need to use OAuth version 1.0A.

Hope this helps for others !